# How do i get day of a particular month and year using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find Starting day of a month using JavaScript by using a function. e.g:

```
function startday(month , year) {
    return sday;
 }
```

This function takes two argument as given year and month. Now I want to calculate its start day.

e.g. `startday(5,2014)` should return Thursday or any number that can be identified , any help will be appreciated.

I do not want to use any library like datePicker, jQuery UI, etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: First decide what you want, JS or jQuery? Because even jQuery is a Library

Comment: You can use JQuery , since i am using JQuery for all as i mentioned not willing to use JQuery UI , e.t.c JQuery PLugin .

Comment: @Yoshi tried as                                              function createCalender()
{
    year=$('#selectYear > option:selected').val();
 month=$('#selectMonth > option:selected').val();
 curDate = new Date();
    var curYear = curDate.getFullYear();
 var curDay = curDate.getDate();
 var curMonth = curDate.getMonth();
 console.log(curYear);
 console.log(curMonth);
 console.log(curDay);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Date object and return the result of [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jd4CL/)**

```
function startday(month , year) {
   var d = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
   return d.getDay();
 } 

startday(5, 2014);
```

This outputs the numerical identifier, so 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday and so on.

You can expand on this to return the full day name by using an array:

```
function startday(month , year) {
   var weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
   var d = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
   return weekdays[d.getDay()];
 } 

console.log(startday(5, 2014));
```

Outputs: Thursday

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this -

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2014,4,1);  // 0 - january , 1 Feb .....  (yyyy,mm,dd)
myDate.getDay();  // 0 -> monday , 1 -> tuesday ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var day = daysInMonth(5,2014) ;
function daysInMonth(month,year) 
{
   return new Date(year, month ,1).getDay();
}
```

Output: 0 -> Sunday.

here, the month field goes from *0-11* and not *1-12*.

If you need to pass parameter with *1-12* logic use :

```
var day = daysInMonth(5,2014) ;
function daysInMonth(month,year) 
{
   return new Date(year, month-1 ,1).getDay();
}
```

You need a javascript Date() object.

Here is a Demo **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/Ra8a4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function startday(month , year)
{ 
   var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1); // this is for First Day of month
   var lastDay = new Date(year, month +1, 0); // this is for Last Day of month
   var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
   var day = firstDay.getDay(); // it will return number (0-6)
   return days[day];   // days[day] returns Day like Monday
}
```

I am providing entire source code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the date after changing the day of the month.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = startday(05,2014);
}

function startday(month , year)
{ 
   var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
   document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = firstDay;
   var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
   return days[firstDay.getDay()];
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```